# Apache Newbie Confused - Can't make directory listing work

Tags: server, apache2, directory

Hopefully some of you can help me out.

I'm a beginner when it comes to Apache and am trying to teach myself its core elements by going through the groundwork to set up a server with DirectoryListing and Password Authentication in my VMware on ubuntu.

**What I want to accomplish:**
Be able to connect to "site1.com" and see a directory listing such as: 
https://imgur.com/a/gFhdY

**My issue is the following:**

I have the following code in my config file within /etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.com.conf (forgive the formatting, first post on here in years):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin serveradmin@admin.com
ServerName site1.com
ServerAlias www.site1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/site1.com/public_html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

 <Directory "/var/www/site1.com/public_html>
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Restricted Content"
 AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
 Require valid-user
 Options Indexes
 Index Options FoldersFirst IgnoreCase
 </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

The password authentication works just fine, but I'm not sure *where* I'm supposed to put files to see if the Directory Listing works or if the Directory Listing simply doesn't work. When I connect to site1.com on my virtual machine, I simply see the contents of index.html within `/var/www/site1.com/public_html/index.html` and see no files listed.

Since the DocumentRoot is set to /var/www/site1.com/public_html, I assume this is where I place files. I've created a file called Test4.html and a folder called FolderTest within this directory for testing purposes, but as I wrote above, I'm not sure if these are in the right format or if they're even in the right place.

I've tried affixing a "+" before Indexes, so that it reads `Options +Indexes` but that didn't work either.

Any and all help would really be appreciated as I feel completely stuck and am unsure of where to go from here.

Kind regards,
Victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `index.html`. The directory index is displayed only if an index file does not exist.

Comment: Thank you so much! This begs the question, what purpose does index.html serve? Also: how do i select your answer as the best answer? :)

Comment: To accept the answer click on the check mark beside it!

Comment: Some people want to show a web page on their site, not a list of files. ;)

Comment: index.html is the default home page for a web site. with this file, you can just type in the web address and not have to specify the page ie http://example.com instead of http://example.com/home.html.